# What is the best way to use ClaimsAuthorizationModule in Azure Service Fabric stateless service

Tags: .net, web-services, azure, wcf, azure-service-fabric

I'm migrating several WCF services currently hosted in Azure Cloud Services to an Azure Service Fabric Cluster.

But the WCF Services use the ClaimsAuthorizationModule from the web server, as defined in the web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

BUT, in Azure Service Fabric the services are self hosted, there's no IIS or web server.

What is the best way to do the same in a Stateless Service in Azure Service Fabric?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this thread which will help in your query - [Register MicroServices in Azure Active Directory (AAD) for Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890804/register-microservices-in-azure-active-directory-aad-for-security)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't use Active Directory for authentication. I use a custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager, and changing that is not an option at this point.